# My laptop is booting to black screen

Tags: boot

I run fix installation command after which terminal removed all the files and now it is showing this black screen.

How can I repair my system?

[image]

Comment: Do you still get to Grub?

Comment: Laptop starts it loads os(orange screen comes with all the recovery options advanced option etc)and then it shows that black screen

Comment: @NerdOfCode yes grub>advanced option>generic then this black screen pops up